# Strengths and limitations of arrays

Tags: data-structures, arrays

What are the strengths and limitations of arrays? What considerations go into choosing an array over another data structure, or vice-versa?

Comment: The question is too broad. Could you list that you want to compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple answer is;

- Arrays

  - allow fast random access in $\mathcal{O}(1)$ to their elements since and they are sequential in memory.
  - $\mathcal{O}(1)$ time write or update an element
  - if not created in heap memory size is very limited.
  - The size is fixed.
- Vectors

  - Access and write is similar to array
  - The size not fixed. When capacity is full, extended.